# Initializing function pointer to new function in C

Tags: c, function-pointers

I would like to convert

```
typedef double (*Function)(double s[4]);
double f1 (double x[N]) {return x[0]*x[1];}
Function t = f1;
```

to something like this:

```
typedef double (*Function)(double s[4]);
Function t = ({ return x[0]*x[1];});
```

which returns a "void value not ignored as it ought to be" error.
How can I make this work?

Comment: C doesn't have lambdas unless this is a compiler specific extension.

Comment: @SuperStormer dirty workaround in my answer - but requires nested functions extension.

Answer (score 2):

C does not have anonymous functions or lambda expressions. So it is not possible.

---

**EDIT: PSEUDO LAMBDA**

Tiny dirty workaround for the compilers which allow nested functions:

```
#define lmb(rt, fb)({rt fn__fn__fn_ fb fn__fn__fn_; })

int main(void)
{
    double (*f)(double x[]) = lmb(double, (double x[]) { return x[0] * x[1]; });
    double  x[] = {4.0, 5.0};

    printf("%f\n", f(x));
}
```